# Tag Contact Via Link in Email

Tags: email, activities, tags

Is it possible to build a url to be included in an email sent from CiviCRM such that when the user clicks the link, they will automatically be tagged with a term in the system? Or maybe add an activity to their record? Basically I'm looking for a way to do a 1-click and done action to track some things in the system.

Forgot to mention I am using Drupal.

Comment: It would help if you specify your CMS since I can imagine that Drupal might offer some options eg, link back to a webform which user submits, result being user gets tagged. not quite one-click, but closer than civi offers out of the box

Comment: Thanks, yes I am looking at the webform route as a worst case scenario, but was hoping someone had a cool one click solution.

Comment: Understood. We all hope for the Cool One Click Extension at times

Comment: You could add a little js to the webform to make it autosubmit as soon as it's loaded.

Comment: Could something be created with CiviEntity and Rules?  Perhaps: The email has a link to a particular node and the URL includes a token for the contact's Civi ID. Then when that node is viewed, the Contact ID from the URL is fetched and then a tag is added to that Contact ID?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a Drupal webform as follows:

- Contact 1 - current user (if not logged in you'd need a checksum)
- Contact 2 - the person to be tagged - set this as "existing contact" prepopulated from the url.
- The tag will have to be preselected in the webform, so you'd have do clone this webform for each tag you want.
- Add a tiny bit of javascript to the form to make it auto-submit.
- On submit, redirect or display a success message.